# closure of the unit ball

Tags: metric-spaces

Is the closure of the unit ball of $C^1[0,1]$ in $C[0,1]$ compact?

For this let us take a sequence $x_n$ in $C^1[0,1]$ to show it has a convergent subseqence

How to proceed with this.I am not so sure whether  it is the way to ask a question here

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280546/the-closure-of-the-unit-ball-of-c10-1-in-c0-1-and-its-compactness).